# How to generate a proper event.json for a lambda called from API Gateway to run it locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, api-gateway, serverless-application-model

I have a an aws lambda that I would like to be able to invoke locally utilizing `sam local invoke "MyFunction" -e event.json`, but my event.json file never seems to be correct.  For example, if my lambda connects to DynamoDB, I get an error like "The security token included in the request is invalid."

Is there a way to run a functional lambda in the cloud and generate/output the event.json (e.g. as if it were invoked from API Gateway) so that you can then use it locally?

Comment: Can you run it once in lambda, not locally, save `event` into CW logs, and then use that as a template for your local executions?

Comment: That sounds plausible.  Let me try that.  I think to add further confusion, I am using the streaming handler and I wasn't sure how to get ahold of the event https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/master/sample-apps/java-basic/src/main/java/example/HandlerStream.java

Comment: @Marcin Yeah, I think part of my problem is that using a streaming handler with an inputStream and outputStream while also using a {proxy+} with Java, it doesn't seem straight-forward on how to print that event out so I can see it in CloudWatch.  I continue to get strange errors while trying to copy direct examples.

Comment: What about [sam local generate-event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-generate-event.html)? Maybe it has event that could be of use to you?

Comment: @Marcin this certainly helped, thank you.  I think it serves my needs for now.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind, I will post an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments.

SAM has number of **test events** available for use from many different services, including api gateway and dynamodb.

The test events can be accessed using [sam local generate-event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-generate-event.html) command.